# SlidingMenu error on setadapter

Tags: android, slidingmenu

Hej Community! After a long search I decides to ask by myself. :)

I got a problem with the SlidingMenu library from jeremyfeinstein.

If I set the ListView in a fragment and make an ArrayAdapter for that I get an Exception on the setadapter line.

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu" };

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
      list.add(values[i]);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Please help! And sorry for the noobish question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your `ListView` is inside fragment you cannot access it in activity by

```
findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

try to do all this inside `onCreateView` of the fragment instead.

Comment: But my listview is in the xml fragment and I only have the mainactivity.java. So how do I manage this? Sorry if this sounds ridiculously to you but I just started android programming atwo weeks ago (of course with some java skills).

Comment: So get.the list fragment in activity by calling findFragmentById on fragment manager and set adapter.to.that l.

Comment: Maybe I'm too stupid but I really don't get it.
Here's my code if you're so kind to look through.
Thank you so much for the quick answers!
http://pastebin.com/t68citrP

Answer (score 0):

You may do like this:

```
ListView listview = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);
```